# Eagle library multiple packages in one device?

Tags: eaglecad, cad

So in an Eagle library, the device is created by joining schematic symbols with pcb packages.  You can have more than one symbol in a package... (a quad opamp).  Is there anyway to have multiple packages linked to one symbol?

Comment: When you say "multiple packages linked to one symbol", do you mean that one symbol would correspond to several optional packages?  (For example,  an OpAmp comes in 8-SOIC, and the same OpAmp also comes in 8-DIP).

Comment: @NickAlexeev, No I know how to do that.  So (on a previous pcb) I had a panel mounted pot with wires to the pcb.  It sometimes would be nice to move the pads for the pot around some... I can do this by making the pot three different pads... but it would be nice keep the pads linked with the pot symbol on the schematic... As it is I just put words on the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, [that](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241912/eagle-library-multiple-packages-in-one-device?noredirect=1#comment528618_241912) isn't possible to do with the present Eagle library stricture.  You can not have one symbol that corresponds to several footprints on the PCB, which you can move independently.

I can think of a workaround.
[Haven't tried this with Eagle myself, so this is hypothetical.]
3 separate terminals for the potentiometer (wire terminals, say W1, W2, W3).  Each one is a separate part.  Put the terminals into their own hierarchical block.  Treat this hierarchical block as a schematic symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In Eagle terminology, you create a "variant" of the part. Each variant (usually indicated by a suffix on the base name of the part) links a different package with the schematic symbol.

Comment: Yeah thanks Dave,  I do that already... I want to have many packages on the pcb associated with one symbol.  It's OK I already made a new part.